Attempting to freeze a part of scroll area in tkinter using python in Windows
I am using python 3.11.9 in windows.
Here is my minimum verifiable code:
import tkinter as tk

class Table(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, header_labels:tuple,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        # configuration for all Labels
        # easier to maintain than directly inputting args
        self.lbl_cfg = {
            'master'     : self,
            'foreground' : 'blue',
            'relief'     : 'solid',
            'font'       : 'Arial 20 bold',
            'padx'       : 5,
            'pady'       : 0,
            'bd'         : 1,
            'bg'         : 'white',
        }
        self.headers = []
        self.rows    = []
        for col, lbl in enumerate(header_labels):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)
            # make and store header
            (header := tk.Label(text=lbl, **self.lbl_cfg)).grid(row=0, column=col, sticky='nswe')
            self.headers.append(header)
            
    def add_row(self, desc:str, rate:int, quantity:int, amt:int) -> None:
        print('adding a row to table')
        self.rows.append([])
        for col, lbl in enumerate( ((str(len(self.rows))),desc, rate, quantity, amt) ):
            (entry := tk.Label(text=lbl, **self.lbl_cfg)).grid(row=len(self.rows), column=col, sticky='nswe')
            self.rows[-1].append(entry)

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, title:str="Bill generation", x:int=0, y:int=0, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title(title)
        self.config(**kwargs)
#DEFAULTS
        
#Fixed Entries
        header_labels = ('\u2193','Description','Rate','Quantity','Amt','\u2191')

#KEYBOARD SHORTCUTS
#FONT SETTINGS
        self.gui_lbl_look = {
            'foreground' : 'black',
            'relief'     : 'flat',
            'font'       : 'Arial 18 bold',
            'padx'       : 0,
            'pady'       : 0,
            'borderwidth': 1,
        }
        self.gui_btn_look = {
            'foreground' : 'red',
            'relief'     : 'groove',
            'font'       : 'Arial 18 bold',
            'padx'       : 0,
            'pady'       : 0,
        }
        self.gui_entry_look = {
            'foreground' : 'blue',
            'font'       : 'Arial 18 bold',
            'highlightbackground'   :"black",
            'highlightthickness'    : 2,
            'highlightcolor'        :"blue",
            'insertbackground'      :"blue",
            'insertwidth'           :3,
        }
        self.gui_total_lbl_look = {
            'foreground' : 'green',
            'relief'     : 'solid',
            'font'       : 'Arial 18 bold',
        }
#Text input check
#GUI 
    #bill number and print button
# Second row 
        self.second_row_frame=tk.Frame(self)
        self.second_row_frame.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky='W',pady=5)
# Goods return field
        self.lbl_return=tk.Label(self.second_row_frame,text="GR:",**self.gui_lbl_look)
        self.lbl_return.grid(column =0, row =0)
        self.return_str=tk.StringVar()
        self.return_value=tk.Entry(self.second_row_frame,width=5,textvariable=self.return_str,**self.gui_entry_look)
        self.return_value.grid(column=1,row=0,padx=(0,5))
#description field
        self.default_txt_for_desc=tk.StringVar()
        self.default_txt_for_desc.set("PCS")
        self.txt_desc=tk.Entry(self.second_row_frame,width=10,textvariable=self.default_txt_for_desc,**self.gui_entry_look)
        self.txt_desc.grid(column=2,row=0)
# rate field
        self.lbl_rate=tk.Label(self.second_row_frame,text="Rate:",**self.gui_lbl_look)
        self.lbl_rate.grid(column=3,row=0,padx=(5,0))
        self.rate_str=tk.StringVar() 
        self.txt_rate=tk.Entry(self.second_row_frame,width=4,textvariable=self.rate_str,**self.gui_entry_look)
        self.txt_rate.grid(column=4,row=0)
# quantity field
        self.lbl_qty=tk.Label(self.second_row_frame,text="Qty:",**self.gui_lbl_look)
        self.lbl_qty.grid(column=5,row=0,padx=(5,0))
        self.qty_str=tk.StringVar() 
        self.txt_qty=tk.Entry(self.second_row_frame,width=3,textvariable=self.qty_str,**self.gui_entry_look)
        self.txt_qty.grid(column=6,row=0)
#Item amount
        self.lbl_amt=tk.Label(self.second_row_frame,text="Amount:",**self.gui_lbl_look,bd=1,anchor="e",justify="right")
        self.lbl_amt.grid(column=7,row=0,padx=(5,0))
        self.txt_amt=tk.Label(self.second_row_frame,text='0',width=5,**self.gui_lbl_look,bd=1,anchor="w",justify="left")
        self.txt_amt.grid(column=8,row=0)
#Add to table button
        self.btn_add=tk.Button(self.second_row_frame,text="Add",command=self.clicked,**self.gui_btn_look)
        self.btn_add.grid(column=9,row=0,padx=5)
# Third row entry Table
        self.content_frame=tk.Frame(self,highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
        self.content_frame.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky='news')
        self.canvas=tk.Canvas(self.content_frame,bg='sky blue')
        scrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(self.content_frame,orient="vertical",command=self.canvas.yview,width=50)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.table_frame=tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.table_frame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='news')
        self.table_frame.bind("<Configure>",lambda e:self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))
        self.content_frame.columnconfigure(0,weight=2)
        self.content_frame.rowconfigure(0,weight=2)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0),window=self.table_frame,anchor="nw")
        self.frame_id=self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window=self.table_frame,anchor="nw")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nswe")
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>",self._on_mousewheel)
        scrollbar.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="ns")
        self.table_frame.trial_var=0
        self.table = Table(self.table_frame,header_labels)
        self.table.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nswe')
#virtual keyboard
        self.keyboard_frame=tk.Frame(self,highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
        self.keyboard_frame.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky='se',padx=(10,55))
        self.info_label=tk.Label(self,text=" New bill:space \n Cancel:x \n GR:F1 \n Rate:F2 \n Qty:F3 \n Print:F10 ",**self.gui_total_lbl_look)
        self.info_label.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky='ne',padx=(10,55))
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        for numbers in range(1,11):
            self.add_number_button=tk.Button(self.keyboard_frame,text=str(numbers%10),**self.gui_btn_look)
            self.add_number_button.grid(column=int(numbers-1)%3,row=int((numbers-1)/3))
        self.clear_button=tk.Button(self.keyboard_frame,text='Del',**self.gui_btn_look)
        self.clear_button.grid(column=1,row=3,columnspan=2,sticky='e')
        self.enter_button=tk.Button(self.keyboard_frame,text='Enter',**self.gui_btn_look)
        self.enter_button.grid(column=0,row=4,columnspan=3,sticky='')
#maximizing table cell
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
#Total quantity amount and balance
        self.totals_frame=tk.Frame(self)
        self.totals_frame.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky='')
        self.lbl_tot_qty=tk.Label(self.totals_frame,text="Total Quantity:",**self.gui_total_lbl_look)
        self.lbl_tot_qty.grid(column=0,row=0,padx=5)
        self.lbl_tot_amt=tk.Label(self.totals_frame,text="Total Amount:",**self.gui_total_lbl_look)
        self.lbl_tot_amt.grid(column=1,row=0,padx=5)
        self.lbl_bal=tk.Label(self.totals_frame,text="Balance:",**self.gui_total_lbl_look)
        self.lbl_bal.grid(column=2,row=0,padx=5)
        
        # update so we can get the current dimensions           
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.state('zoomed')
        #FOR LINUX self.attributes('-zoomed',True)
        # test

    def _on_mousewheel(self,event):
        print('scroll in table')
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")

    def clicked(self):
        text_qty=(self.txt_qty.get()).lstrip('0')
        text_rate=(self.txt_rate.get()).lstrip('0')
        item_amt=int(text_rate)*int(text_qty)
        print('adding to table')
        desc=self.txt_desc.get().upper()
        self.table.add_row(desc,int(text_rate),int(text_qty),item_amt)
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application(title="Bill printing app").mainloop()

In this code when you enter numbers in GR , Rate and Qty entries then press add button then a row gets added to table.
Now my problem is that when number of rows exceed the screen and we scroll downward then i want that headers of table (description, rate quantity, amt )should remain in their place.
Can you help me in this?
Here is the screenshot when scroll bar is on top

Here is the screenshot when scroll bar is at bottom

I have tried to post relevant code, which you can easily run on your end.
Please let me know if you need any other details.
Thanks.

Can't you just put the headers in a different frame, above the canvas that scrolls? That should keep the table headers in place while you scroll through the contents of the table.
In response to your comment:
Ah right, I see what you mean in the comment. In that case, you could place the table headers using .place in the content frame. That will ensure that the headers will remain in the same spot, even when scrolling the canvas. You can then dynamically change the size of the table headers if warranted. This can probably be done more efficiently, but this works for me. See my altered Table class:
class Table(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, master, header_labels:tuple,*args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
    # configuration for all Labels
    self.lbl_cfg = {
        'foreground' : 'blue',
        'relief'     : 'solid',
        'font'       : 'Arial 20 bold',
        'padx'       : 5,
        'pady'       : 0,
        'bd'         : 1,
        'bg'         : 'white',
    }
    self.headers        = []
    self.rows           = []
    self.header_widths  = []
    x = 2
    for col, lbl in enumerate(header_labels):
        self.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)
        # make and store header
        (header := tk.Label(self, text=lbl, **self.lbl_cfg)).grid(row=0, column=col, sticky='nswe')
        width = header.winfo_reqwidth()
        header = tk.Label(self.master.master.master, text=lbl, **self.lbl_cfg)
        header.place(x=x, y=2)
        x += width
        
        self.headers.append(header)
        self.header_widths.append(width)
        
def add_row(self, desc:str, rate:int, quantity:int, amt:int) -> None:
    redrawing_headers = False
    self.rows.append([])
    for col, lbl in enumerate( ((str(len(self.rows))),desc, rate, quantity, amt) ):
        (entry := tk.Label(self, text=lbl, **self.lbl_cfg)).grid(row=len(self.rows), column=col, sticky='nswe')
        self.rows[-1].append(entry)
        
        if entry.winfo_reqwidth() > self.header_widths[col]:
            self.header_widths[col] = entry.winfo_reqwidth()
            redrawing_headers = True
    
    if redrawing_headers:
        self.redraw_headers()

def redraw_headers(self):
    x = 2
    for col, header in enumerate(self.headers):
        width = self.header_widths[col]
        header.place(x=x, y=2, width=width)
        x += width

So I first gridded the table headers to calculate the space required. I then placed the headers on the content frame (which is the master.master.master of self in this case). I appended the widths to a variable to check for the need to resize.
Once again, this is surely not optimal. If anyone else has a better idea, I'd love to hear it. But for now, my approach seems to work.

headers are part of the table . they expand as per contents of table . do you mean something else ?

is it possible to have table header in different frame and its contents in another ?

I edited my original answer in response to your comments.

i will try it . Thanks .

Very smooth . You are an expert . Thanks a lot .

In my full code - there was a delete button in every row of table which when clicked deletes the entire row . After our table headers have been expanded on addition of row with big numbers , how can i reduce their size on that row deletion ? Thanks.

i resolved that by keeping original header widths separately then on deletion I restore to original widths and expand a column if its remaining table cells have higher width than original.

Yeah, that sounds about right! Good job.
